# Laravel validate array of objects issue

Tags: php, json, laravel, validation, dingo-api

I have a request in which I pass an array of JSON objects. It has the following structure

```
[ {path: 'string', class: 'string'} ]
```

As far as I understand there is no easy way to check this array so I've tried next

```
$validatedData = $request->validated();

        $result = ['data' => []];
        foreach ($validatedData['items'] as $item) {
            $result['data'][] = json_decode($item);
        }

        Validator::make($result, [
            'data.*.path' => 'required|url',
            'data.*.class' => 'required|string'
        ])->validate();
```

However it results in

```
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#813 (2) {
      ["link"]=>
      NULL
      ["class"]=>
      NULL
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#814 (2) {
      ["link"]=>
      NULL
      ["class"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
```

Somehow a validator cuts off the data. When I try without `Validator::make` part it works fine, however I need to control what I retrieve.

Comment: try put `$result = [];`

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to validate the JSON input?  I'm a bit confused on your problem and why you'd have to decode the JSON and build a result array to begin with.  Are you sending JSON in a non-json request?

Comment: I'm sending a FormData with a `JSON.stringify`ed field. This field contains array. Since it's a JSON PHP considers it as a string so that I'm forced to find workarounds

Comment: Any particular reason?  Why not just send a json request?

Comment: You have an array of objects since json_decode returns an object. For it to return an associative array, you need to do `json_decode($item, true)`. Try it and see if that works.

Comment: Because I *need* to send a FormData. It contains a file.

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata well.. That worked somehow. However I'm curious why it didn't work with an array of objects

Comment: Seems reasonable since stdclass objects would never exist in a request.

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata please post your answer I'll mark it. If possible please expand your explanation for those who new and got stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an array of objects, since `json_decode` returns an object. For it to return an associative array, you need to do `json_decode($item, true)`. You need to do that because the Laravel validator need both the data and the validation rules to be arrays. Since you were passing an array of objects, it didn't work.